# Change of Kendo Grid Dropdownlist should change another kendogrid Dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two kendo grids
Grid1:  Column1: DropdownList   Column2: DropdownList
1. Request          1. Request
2. Ignore               2. Ignore

Grid2: Column1: DropdownList        Column2: DropdownList
1. Preliminary             1. Preliminary
2. Request             2. Request
3. Ignore                      3. Ignore
4. Hold                    4. Hold

I have to implement when user select Request or Ignore in Grid1 Column1, then Grid2 Column1 should change to Ignore.
How to implement this on Change event?
Please help me with some suggestions.

Comment: Is this change to occur on all rows in the 2nd grid, or the same row index? In other words, if I select dropdown list in Grid 1 , but on row 5, am I to make this change to grid 2 on row 5, or is this change to occur on all rows in grid 2? So, you left out what rows we are to operate on here. So, we need this detail - What row on the grid 2 is to be changed here say if we change say row 2 on grid 1?

Comment: Only one row will be there in both grids  and column count is same in both. All the columns in both grids are dropdown lists. If we change 2nd column in grid1 change should occur on the 2nd column in grid2.

Comment: Ok then, so we have two grids, but each grid only has one row. So then the question is we select a drop down list in row 1 of grid 1, and we want to send those changes to the 2nd grid, and apply that to row 1 of grid 2. Ok, then I'll post a working as to how to do this in a bit - going for coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so now we have the problem defined.

We have 2 grids, but ONLY one row in each. We are to select a value in the first grid (dropdown list), and then we want this to selection and change to be applied to the first and only one row in the 2nd grid view, and of course same control (column) in the 2nd grid.

I don't have your data, but lets setup this up to copy a check box, and a combo box. (so two control examples - and how to copy the value from one gird to the other).

So, here is our markup:

(two grids - they are much the same.

```
<div style="float:left;width:40%">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" SortExpression="HotelName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server"
                        Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>'
                        OnCheckedChanged="chkActive_CheckedChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rating">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboRank" runat="server"
                        DataTextField="Rating"
                        DataValueField="ID"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboRank_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ranking" HeaderText="Ranking" SortExpression="Ranking" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>


<div style="float:left;width:40%;margin-left:15px">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CssClass="table"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" SortExpression="HotelName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server"
                        Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rating">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboRank" runat="server"
                        DataTextField="Rating"
                        DataValueField="ID" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ranking" HeaderText="Ranking" SortExpression="Ranking" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

And note above, the first grid - we have a event for the check box, and for hte combo box.

And our code to load:

```
Dim rstRank As New DataTable
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    ' load combo box data source
    rstRank = MyRst("SELECT ID, Rating FROM tblRating")

    Dim rstGridData As DataTable
    rstGridData = MyRst("SELECT * from tblHotels where ID = 77")

    GridView1.DataSource = rstGridData
    GridView1.DataBind()
    GridView2.DataSource = rstGridData
    GridView2.DataBind()

End Sub

Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function
```

So, we now have this:

[image]

So, now our check box code, and combo code (you change the value on left side, it will update and change the 2nd grid on the right side:

```
Protected Sub chkActive_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' check box changed on first grid - update 2nd one
    Dim ckBox As CheckBox = sender
    ' now get 2nd grid view - row 1
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = GridView2.Rows(0)
    Dim ckTarget As CheckBox = gRow.FindControl("chkActive")
    ckTarget.Checked = ckBox.Checked

End Sub

Protected Sub cboRank_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim cboRank As DropDownList = sender
    ' now get 2nd grid view  row 1
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = GridView2.Rows(0)
    Dim cboRankTarget As DropDownList = gRow.FindControl("cboRank")
    cboRankTarget.SelectedValue = cboRank.SelectedItem.Value

End Sub
```

So above has both combo box, and check box examples.

If you change the check box on left side, then we update the one on the right side (2nd grid).

And same goes for the combo box. You change the one on the left side, then the one on the right side is updated to the same value.

So, be it a check box, or combo box, or just say 4 combo box, the above code would work quite much the same.

Just keep in mind that on the left side grid (grid 1), we set auto postback - true for the check box, and the combo box - so they will run their respective code behind when you change a value - and thus that code can now go get the 1st row of grid 2, and then find the control, and then set/change it value to the same one just selected in grid 1

The only other code I had? Well, on the row databound event, I had this same code for both grids - that was code to load and setup the combo box.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        ' load up combo box
        Dim cbo As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("cboRank")

        cbo.DataSource = rstRank
        cbo.DataBind()
        cbo.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select", 0))
        Dim gData As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem

        If Not IsDBNull(gData.Item("Ranking")) Then
            cbo.SelectedValue = gData.Item("Ranking")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

As noted, this load up and setup combo box code was the same for both grid 1, and grid 2